# How to set the IP address in a customized OpenWRT compilation

Tags: ip-address, openwrt

I have been struggling today customizing OpenWRT. I checkout the stable using SVN, "make menuconfig" to customize the image, "make" it and run it on a router. Almost all my modifications work, except for the (Seemingly trivial) task of changing the default 192.168.1.1 address.

I tried numerous files (scripts as well as config files) but I can't seem to change it (I can change it for a brief moment after boot using the "preinit" file, but after a few seconds it reverts to default).

I suspect I should be setting it in the /etc/network file, but modifications there seem to be overwritten during boot. Maybe it has something to do with the br-lan interface?

Does anybody have some thoughts on the subject?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... Found out how the cookie crumbles via the OpenWRT Forum.

You have to make a "files" folder in your build dir eg. "~OpenWRT/trunk/files". You can then add files and folders as is were the root folder of your build.

Example:

```
"/files/etc/banner"
```

would enable you to make a custom banner (for telnet or SSH)

[Article on OpenWRT Forum](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=21297)

Alternatively you can use the buildroot's menuconfig to set specific configuration options as well under the Image Configuration submenu. [Image Configuration](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build#image.configuration)